# internal microphone not working in viber on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, microphone, viber

I am having problem with audio device in viber. I am unable to use mic in viber.

Also, the sound in internal speaker is very noisy(something like perrr,perrr) when the calling tone plays in viber but it becomes clear after few seconds .

Webcam works fine.

To test if microphone is working I downloaded Audacity, and it records my sound very fine.These problems occur only in viber.

The audio video settings in viber is as in picture below:

[image: audio video settings:Audio Input:Built-in Audio Analog Stereo,Audio Output:Built-in Audio Analog Stereo]

The sound settings in ubuntu is as in picture below:

[image]

Also, when I choose Built-in Audio Digital Stereo(HDMI) in Audio Output, I don't hear any sound.

The output of cat /proc/asound/cards is:

```
0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                  HDA Intel HDMI at 0xc0710000 irq 50
1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xc0714000 irq 49
29 [ThinkPadEC     ]: ThinkPad EC - ThinkPad Console Audio Control
                  ThinkPad Console Audio Control at EC reg 0x30, fw unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

installed GNOME ALSA Mixer through software center.

opened it and there was column for "internal".

in that column , I dragged the slide bar to the left (so that it was no longer orange in my case).

now its working fine in both skype and viber.